# Script not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to move the following page

http://cliponexpress.com/customize-your-clipon.html

Into this wordpress page

http://cliponexpress.com/customizeit/

The script below changes the images when the thumbnails are clicked. it works fine on the html page, however I can't get it to work on wordpress, no matter where I place it (tried header, footer and within the page itself).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.thumbnail').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('href');
    var output = src.split('/').pop().split('.').shift();
    $("#os1").val(output);
    $("#os1_text").text(output);
    if (src != $('img#lens').attr('src').replace(/\?(.*)/, '')) {
        $('img#lens').stop().animate({
            opacity: '0'
        }, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', src + '?' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 * 100)));
        }).load(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: '1'
            });
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$('a.thumbnail2').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('href');
    var output = src.split('/').pop().split('.').shift();
    $("#os0").val(output);
    $("#os0_text").text(output);
    if (src != $('img#chassis').attr('src').replace(/\?(.*)/, '')) {
        $('img#chassis').stop().animate({
            opacity: '0'
        }, function() {
            $(this).attr('src', src + '?' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 * 100)));
        }).load(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: '1'
            });
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Comment: And you should put your code inside `jQuery(document).ready(function{ [..] your code here[...] }` if you add this in the head.

Comment: Adding jQuery instead of $ worked. thanks Tushar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function(){
      alert('test');
     /*ADD YOUR CODE HERE*/
   });
}(jQuery));
</script>
```